# How to get property or method in relationship ( laravel - eloquent )

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

in Post Model

```
function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( \App\User::class);
}
```

in User Model

```
function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany( \App\Post::class);
}


function somedata() 
{
    return  date('i') * 1000  + date('s'); 
}
```

in Controller

```
$posts = Post::query()
        ->where('id', 10)
        ->with('user')
        ->get();
```

but it does not get 'somedata' in user model .

How can I drag this data with posts ?

Comment: Did you try `$posts->first()->somedata();`. `$posts` should be a `Collection` of objects.

Comment: Your $posts is collection so you need to use loop $posts as $post and access $post->user->somedata method

Answer (score 2):

Try making it an attribute and append it in the model
`Post.php`

```php
/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $appends = ['someData'];

/**
 * Get the some data for the post.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getSomeDataAttribute()
{
    return  date('i') * 1000  + date('s');
}
```

Comment: You SO GOOD. Thanks . and I wish I can find some doc about eloquent model reserved keywords something..

Comment: There you go [Eloquent Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an Accessor:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class User extends Model
    {
        /**
         * Get the user's somedata.
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getSomedataAttribute()
        {
            return 'somedata';
        }
    }
```

Also see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Comment: Great start @robert but he needs to append it as well.

Comment: Isn't $append only if I want to return property into a JSON ?

Comment: @Robert-GabrielSTANCIU all Eloquent models get automatically serialized to JSON when returned in a response

Comment: Sure, but adding 'somedata' to $appends would help if he's using the response into a SPA. He can still access $user->somedata even if he doesn't add 'somedata' to $appends